# Precise Positioning of charts (plot areas) in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to left-align two plot areas in two separate charts.  Both charts have a single x-axis and two y-axes.  I have tried using the following code (which I obtained via the Macro Recorder), but the charts are not aligned.  I have also included a picture of the problem.  What am I missing?

EDIT: I should add that `Chart2` has the same width but a different height than `Chart1` (as seen in the code).  If I set the dimensions for the charts to be the same, they align perfectly.  I thought that the `Left` and `Top` alignment would align the plot areas vertically since they both have the same width (1140)).

VBA:

```
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart1").Width = 1200
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
    Selection.Left = 10
    Selection.Top = 8
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
    Selection.Width = 1140
    Selection.Height = 310

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart2").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart2").Width = 1200
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
    Selection.Left = 10
    Selection.Top = 8
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
    Selection.Width = 1140
    Selection.Height = 110
```

The red dotted lines show the misalignment:

[image]

Comment: First make sure the ChartObject Objects have the same Left property and second, adjust for differences in the Width Property of the Value axis. The Plot Area includes the Axis.

Comment: [INTERESTING READ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the methods InsideLeft and InsideWidth of the plotArea

```
Sub alignPlotArea()
    For Each chtObj In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        chtObj.Activate
        With ActiveChart.PlotArea
          .InsideLeft = 40
          .InsideWidth = 420
        End With
    Next chtObj
End Sub
```